# Wordpress shortcode popup include wp functions

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, popup, shortcode

I added a shortcode button to my tinymce using this tutorial
http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/how-to-make-shortcodes-user-friendly/
This all works fine.

I now want to include some wordpress functions to the popup file in order to make use of 'colorpicker', 'mediainclude', etc.

This is not working.  In my popup file I try to include these scripts to make use of it, but it does not work:

```
$absolute_path = __FILE__;
$path_to_file = explode( 'wp-content', $absolute_path );
$path_to_wp = $path_to_file[0];
// Access WordPress
require_once( $path_to_wp . '/wp-load.php' );
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am trying to use the color picker in a thickbox as well and its not firing.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working last night. I think you are forgetting to enqueue the style for the colorpicker etc. This is how I am enqueueing the scripts.

```
<?php 
if ( !current_user_can('publish_posts') ) exit();

wp_enqueue_script( 
    array( 
        'iris', 
        'json2', 
        'jquery', 
        'jquery-ui-core', 
        'jquery-ui-sortable',
        'jquery-ui-tabs',
        'jquery-ui-slider',
        'jquery-ui-datepicker',
        'jquery-ui-autocomplete',
        'tiny-mce-popup',
        'shortcodes',
        'media-upload', 
        'thickbox',
    )  
); 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker', false, true );          
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker', false, true ); 
?>
```

Not sure why but the last two only worked when done like that.

Then here is the script for the color picker.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var myOptions = {
    // you can declare a default color here,
    // or in the data-default-color attribute on the input
    defaultColor: false,
    // a callback to fire whenever the color changes to a valid color
    change: function(event, ui){},
    // a callback to fire when the input is emptied or an invalid color
    clear: function() {},
    // hide the color picker controls on load
    hide: true,
    // show a group of common colors beneath the square
    // or, supply an array of colors to customize further
    palettes: true
};

$('.my-color-field').wpColorPicker(myOptions);
});
</script>
```

And the HTML to show the color picker.

```
<span class="wp-picker-input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="my-color-field" style="display: none;">
</span>
```

Let me know if that works for you. This is all on my window.php file that is used to populate the content in the thickbox window etc.